# Random grey bar appears on top of ViewController in iOS (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making an app currently and on the main screen where I load multiple items from Parse, I see a weird grey bar. I don't know where this bar came from as it does not show up on the storyboard and I don't know how to fix it. It never was a problem until it randomly recently showed up. Here is the code for that ViewController.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI
import Kingfisher


class HomeTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad ()
    {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setTitle()
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setHeight(0.0)
//        self.tableView.scrollsToTop = true
//        self.tableView.scrollToNearestSelectedRow(at:            UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: false)
//        self.tableView.scrollToNearestSelectedRow(at:      UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
 }

func setTitle()
{
    var parentView = self.parent
    while parent != nil
    {
        if let menu = parentView as? CucuMenuController
        {
//                menu.setTitleForLabel("Cucus")
            menu.setTitleForLabel("")
            break
        }

        parentView = parentView?.parent
    }
}

var firstTime = true
var totalArticles = 0
let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

required init!(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupHomefeed()
}

func setupHomefeed()
{
    // This runs before didFinishLoadingWithOptions
    self.parseClassName = "Article"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = true
    self.objectsPerPage = 10
    self.loadingViewEnabled = true
}

override func objectsDidLoad(_ error: Error?)
{
    super.objectsDidLoad(error)
    if firstTime
    {
        firstTime = false
        self.loadObjects()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else
    {
        PFObject.pinAll(inBackground: self.objects)
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    if PFUser.current() == nil || PFUser.current()!["name"] == nil
    {
        let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginController")
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
    }
    else if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "showDemo")
    {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)
    }
    else
    {
        self.loadObjects()
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if self.objects!.count < totalArticles && self.objects!.count > 0
    {
        return self.objects!.count + 1
    }
    return self.objects!.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if indexPath.row == self.objects?.count
    {
        return 70.0
    }
    else
    {
        return 221.5
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as UITableViewCell!

    if indexPath.row == self.objects!.count
    {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "loadCell") as UITableViewCell!
    }
    if (indexPath.row > self.objects!.count)
    {
        return cell!
    }

    let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(200) as! UIImageView
    let titleText = cell?.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel
    let timeLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(102) as! UILabel
    let newImage = cell?.viewWithTag(100) as! UIImageView
    let diffImage = cell?.viewWithTag(300) as! UIImageView
    let scoreLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(301) as! UILabel
    let catLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(103) as! UILabel
    let article = Article(parseData: self.objects![indexPath.row])

    titleText.text = article.title
    timeLabel.text = article.duration
    catLabel.text = article.category.uppercased()

    let hasRead = UserController.hasReadArticle(article.objectId)
    newImage.isHidden = hasRead

    if hasRead
    {
        let score = UserController.getScoreForArticle(article.objectId)
        scoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "YOUR SCORE: %.0f", score) as String
        var performance = "hard"
        if score >= article.idealScore { performance = "easy" }
        else if score * 2 >= article.idealScore { performance = "medium" }

        diffImage.image = UIImage(named: performance + "ScoreTag")

        if UserController.getPlayableForArticle(article.objectId) {
            cell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
    else
    {
        scoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "AVG. SCORE: %.0f", article.idealScore) as String
        diffImage.image = UIImage(named: article.difficulty.lowercased() + "ScoreTag")
    }

    //Image
    let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: article.getImageURL(), cacheKey: article.objectId)
    imageView.kf.setImage(with: resource)

    UIHelper.addShadowToHomeCell((cell?.viewWithTag(1)!)!)
    return cell!
}

var selectedIndex = -1

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if indexPath.row == self.objects!.count
    {
        self.loadNextPage()
    }
    else
    {
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "detailSegue"
    {
        let dest = segue.destination as? ArticlePreviewViewController
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "showDemo")
        {
            dest?.article = DemoArticle().article
        }
        else
        {
            dest?.article = Article(parseData: self.objects![selectedIndex])
        }
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "CUCU_START"), object: nil)
}

override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery<PFObject>
{
    let q = PFQuery(className: "Article").whereKey("releaseDate", lessThanOrEqualTo: Date()).whereKey("validated", equalTo: true)

    if firstTime
    {
        q.fromLocalDatastore()
    }
    else
    {
        let mods = PFQuery(className: "Question").whereKey("article", matchesQuery: q)
        mods.findObjectsInBackground
            {
            (objects, err) -> Void in
            PFObject.pinAll(inBackground: objects)
        }
    }
    print(firstTime)
    totalArticles = q.countObjects(nil)
    q.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
    return q
}
}
```

Here are a few images of what the problem looks like:

[image: No grey bar in view controller]

[image: Grey bar in simulation]

**Edit 1:**
As suggested in the comments, I even tried to debug view hierarchy but I don't know which element to delete to make the grey bar go away.

[image: Attempt to debug view hierarchy]

[image: Attempt to find source of problem]

Comment: I would run it in the simulator and hit the "Debug View Hierarchy" button and see what it is.  That might give a clue where it's coming from.

Comment: what constraints are you applying on main table view? looks like your table view is starting after some 40 points and your view background color is grey so might be because of that, Check Debug View Hierarchy like Shawn said, and can also share if problem not solved.

Comment: @Shawn I attempted debug view hierarchy but I don't know which element to delete in the view controller. Please help me out. I edited the question and added images of the debug view as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it might be your navigation bar.  Have you tried using this:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

instead of the statement you have of:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

Update #2:

Actually, I just realized you have that in the viewDidLoad.  Move that to viewWillAppear and I bet it will work.

Update #3:

Just to reflect the true fix here, the offending code was in the viewDidAppear:

```
navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

Comment: I added self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true) to viewDidLoad and it did not change anything. But when I removed self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false from viewDidAppear it started working. Thanks! But, could you explain exactly why this works?

Comment: Glad you got it worked out.  As you could see from the debug view hierarchy, that gray bar was your navigation bar with no title text (or buttons).  You were hiding it in viewDidLoad but unhiding it with that code in viewDidAppear.